# DQL cannot resolve primary key through one-to-one relationship as parameter

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I use a one-to-one relationship as an id for an entity:

**Actor entity**

```
$metadata->mapOneToOne([
    'fieldName' => 'user',
    'id' => true,
    'targetEntity' => AbstractUser::class,
    'inversedBy' => 'actor',
    'cascade' => ['all'],
    'joinColumns' => [
        [
            'name' => 'user_id',
            'referencedColumnName' => 'id',
            'nullable' => false,
        ]
    ],
]);
```

and the other side:

**AbstractUser entity**

```
$metadata->mapField([
    'fieldName' => 'id',
    'type' => 'string',
    'length' => 36,
    'id' => true,
    'strategy' => 'none',
    'unique' => true,
]);

$metadata->mapOneToOne([
    'fieldName' => 'actor',
    'targetEntity' => Actor::class,
    'mappedBy' => 'user',
    'cascade' => ['all'],
]);
```

Then I have a third entity (**Subscription**) referencing the **Actor** entity:

```
$metadata->mapManyToOne([
    'fieldName' => 'subscribingActor',
    'targetEntity' => Actor::class,
    'joinColumns' => [
        [
            'name' => 'subscribing_actor_id',
            'referencedColumnName' => 'user_id',
            'nullable' => false,
        ],
    ],
]);
```

The query I try to run looks like this:

```
function findByActors(Actor $subscribingActor, Actor $subscribedActor): ?Subscription
{
    $qb = $this->entityRepository->createQueryBuilder('s');
    $qb
        ->where('s.subscribingActor = :subscribingActor')
        ->setParameter('subscribingActor', $subscribingActor);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

This results in the following exception:

> Object of *InternalUser (extends AbstractUser)* could not be converted to string

If I implement `AbstractUser::__toString()` returning the id of the user everything works fine.

**The strange thing:** if I load the entity freshly from the database, it works. If I create it, persist it and use that every entity object I get the above "to string" error.

My question is now, why is doctrine not able to detect the id value through the `mapOneToOne` -> `joinColumns[0]['referencedColumnName']` information but instead does try to call `__toString()` on the related object although it's clear from the mapping where it could find the PK  value of the related entity but only if the entity is not initially loaded from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow doctrine is just not able to determine the PK of the `Actor` entity through the mapping. Providing the original entity `User` helps doctrine resolving everything:

```php
function findByActors(Actor $subscribingActor, Actor $subscribedActor): ?Subscription
{
    $qb = $this->entityRepository->createQueryBuilder('s');
    $qb
        ->where('s.subscribingActor = :subscribingActor')
        ->setParameter('subscribingActor', $subscribingActor->getUser());
        // or $subscribingActor->getUser()->getId() to be even more explicit

    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test this :

```
    function findByActors(Actor $subscribingActor): ?Subscription
    {
        $qb = $this->entityRepository->createQueryBuilder('s');
        $qb->leftJoin('s.subscribingActor', 'subscribingActor')
            ->where('subscribingActor.id = :subscribingActorId')
            ->setParameter('subscribingActorId', $subscribingActor->getId());

        return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
```

Hope this help